# Loading of a Dynamically created Entity by automatic dyscovery

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, entity, javassist

I have to work with a strange DB structure, where on production there could be more tables but with same columns. And we want to use JPA (Hibernate) with handle them, by entities/JPQL queries. The idea is to create entity classes for each table dynamically within JVM at runtime. This approach works fine. I create Entities with Javassist - using an already existing compiled entity, and I add annotations to it dynamically (Entity, Table):

```
public Class generateGroupStateEntity(String className,String tableName) {
    ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("MyTemplateEntity.class"));
    CtClass c = cp.makeClass(is);
    c.setName(className); 
    ClassFile cf = c.getClassFile();
    ConstPool constPool = cf.getConstPool();


    AnnotationsAttribute annotAtr = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool,AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
    Annotation annot = new Annotation("javax.persistence.Entity", constPool);
    annotAtr.addAnnotation(annot);

    Annotation annotTable = new Annotation("javax.persistence.Table", constPool);
    annotTable.addMemberValue("name", new StringMemberValue(tableName,cf.getConstPool()));
    annotAtr.addAnnotation(annotTable);

    cf.addAttribute(annotAtr);
    return c.toClass();
  }
```

When I build a Hibernate SessionFactory by hand, from a Configuration object, adding this classes using addAnnotatedClass method to Configuration, it works fine. Problem is with automated discovery, the entity is not discovered/found neither by JPA, or by AnnotationSessionFactoryBean - when I use package scanning with within a spring context.
(I get: "QuerySyntaxException: [MyEntity] is not mapped" exception)

Class.forName(myNewEntityName) works that means the it is Initialized within the Classloader.

(Of course I know this is not an Ideal design patter for Handling these tables.)

The question is why and how to sole it?

(Javassist 3.15.0-GA, hibernate core 3.6.6.Final, hibernate-entitymanager 3.5.6-Final)

Comment: My first though is that maybe there is problem with the class loader, where it is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think package scanning happens on the jars and folder in the classpath - not at the classloader level.  This is to optimize not loading all the classes into memory. This [article](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/01/14/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime/) has some details of how it is done.

To solve it you might have to extend the AnnotationSessionFactoryBean - and add the list of classes dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I already implemented a dynamic class adding, i will check the implementation of scanning in spring, but probably this is the problem. thx